repeat a row a specified quantity of times and then fill with a sequence that restarts for each set of rows
Working in Google Sheets...
I am looking to take the following input which can contain any number of rows:
Building #  QTY of Entrances
1   1
2   4
3   2
4   3
5   1

And produce the following array which repeats each input in column A the n times as specified in column B and then places a sequence (1 through n, step by 1) into column B :
Building #  Entrance #
1   1
2   1
2   2
2   3
2   4
3   1
3   2
4   1
4   2
4   3
5   1

I have tried to modify answers in a few threads but have not been able to get it working.


Here's one approach you may test out:
=reduce(tocol(,1),A2:index(A:A,match(,0/(A:A<>""))),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,let(Σ,offset(c,,1),hstack(wrapcols(c,Σ,c),sequence(Σ))))))



try:
=INDEX(SPLIT(TOCOL(MAP(A2:A, B2:B, 
 LAMBDA(a, b, IFERROR(a&"​"&SEQUENCE(1, b)))), 1), "​"))


